# generate gender variables in spark using UDF

Tags: function, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I try to generate a variables (M or F) with udf and I have the following code:

```
@udf
def gender():
    return np.random.choice(["F","M"],p=[0.5,0.5])

second_df.select('ID', gender())
```

however, it does not work. Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am not that experienced in python.

Comment: Doesn't work isn't very helpful. Does it throw an exception, return an incorrect result, something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, I get the following error:

`5 frames
/content/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

    330                 raise Py4JError(`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, I get the following error:

`328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)`

I think this is the correct part of the error code, im trying to learn python hence it might be me missunderstaning the error text. Ive tried to change the format by adding .StringType() to the function but still woun't be able to get it correct. I manged to some other functions to work with float numbers but when I try to use characters it doesn't, hence I though maybe it was some easy fix that I had missed